# Integrate DataProvider TestNG test into List of Keyword java files and call from other java file

Tags: java, selenium, testng, keyword

My Test Automation Framework is KeywordDriven Framework. I want to add a test case which supports dataProvider class of TestNG. I can execute the Test case with DataProvider, separately. But, when I incorporate dataProvider test to Keyword framework, It stops its execution and showed the `null` parameter to that test.

Architecture of Framework is:

My TestSuite File consists all test cases in it.In which first-sheet of excel have all test cases with run mode and rest of the sheets have each test cases.
Second sheet of excel file is TestCase1:
Similarly, all test cases are documented in each sheet of excel file.In above screenshot, ‘keyword’ column against ‘object’. ‘Objects’ are object repository and all ‘Keywords’ are documented in Keyword file.

[demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B865ekOaGf3ULVp1RWJGTGw0eWM)

```
Public class KeywordsApp extends DriverApp{

//Input data Keyword
public static String inputValues() throws Exception{
    String message = "pass";
    String data =testData.getCellData(currentTest, datacolumnname , testRepeat);
    System.out.println("Enter :"+data);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(objects.getProperty(object))).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(objects.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(data);
return "Pass";
}
//click button
public static String clickObject(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(objects.getProperty(object))).click();
    return "Pass";
    }
}
```

In Keyword file, we documented all actions/methods and invoke these methods on mentioned objects.
In This framework, a DriverScript runs all these test cases mentioned in TestSuite excel file. Driver Script reads everything in excel file, load all related properties, excel and XML files, Initiate driver /browser for further execution.

Now, We have few test cases in which we have to perform repetitive actions, for example … we need to add multiple dependents to main profile I.e. 10 to 100 dependents.

We achieved this requirement by using dataProvider class in Testing, separately. But, We don't know, how to add this dataProvider class into Keywords file. So we can execute complete suite in one run.(As per TestSuite excel file).
Testsuite excel file path: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B865ekOaGf3UeWk5dkpTLUJiVWc.

Is there any way, to integrate dataProvider in above mentioned Keyword framework?